# How to change sound driver? (pulse -> oss)

Tags: 11.10, drivers, pulseaudio, oss-sound-system

I think Ubuntu is set by default to use pulse audio driver. How do I change to OSS? Some softwares that I am using only allow this type of sound driver to use corectly the sound system. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has [deprecated OSS support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound) - the kernel no longer supports OSS devices.

> If you're considering using OSS4, you should probably use another
>   Linux distro like Arch Linux

For legacy apps that insist on using a OSS device, you should look at using `padsp` which is the [pulseaudio wrapper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/padsp.1.html) for OSS:

If application foo needs to use OSS devices, simply run: `padsp foo`.

It will emulate /dev/dsp and related devices, and redirect data between foo and these devices to PulseAudio.

Comment: nice fossfreedom. How I should do this for [THIS](http://www.dragons.tl) (since this question is a real fact), and this application looks just like a pre-client, that calls the real one.. whatever.. I have some nice difficulties with CLI. But let me try, "padsp eclient" ?

Comment: If that application has only support for oss and nothing else, then you could try running via `padsp eclient` or similar.  Otherwise, you may have to dual boot with archlinux to play that game :(

Comment: worked like a charm with:  " padsp ./elaunch "  Thank you.