# How to use OSS instead of PulseAudio?

Tags: 12.04, installation, xubuntu, pulseaudio, oss-sound-system

Sound was working fine with PulseAudio, but I installed something in order to try to get xawtv to work, but that just caused the audio to stop working.

So I tried to install some packages to get OSS to work, because I read that OSS is better than PulseAudio (is that true?)

Anyway, I'm unable to get OSS to work either. What packages do I need to install, and how do I get this set up?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/78495/how-to-change-sound-driver-pulse-oss

Answer (score 1):

OSS4 is an alternative for ALSA, not for PulseAudio.

I tried OSS4 with ubuntu, the sound is good, perhaps better than ALSA, but i reverted back to ALSA because of a couple of problems:

1. OSS4 does not detect automatically the plugging in of a headphones jack (at least for my audio card)
2. the flash plugin work bad or crashes with OSS4

Anyway, I have some notes I saved from my short experience:

- add your user to the `audio` group;
- install the package `linux-source`;
- extract the tar archive installed with the previous package in `/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/` (or equivalent, depending on the kernel version)
- create a symlink `/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic-pae/source` to `/usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0/`
- install the packages `oss4-{base,source,dkms,gtk}` and `liboss4-salsa2`
- run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-sound-base` and choose OSS4
- modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

  - comment the line: `load-module module-udev-detect`
  - add the line: `load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input mmap=0`
- run `gstreamer-properties` and choose OSS4
- create `~/.asoundrc` with content:

  ```
  pcm.!default
  {
    type oss
    device /dev/dsp
  }
  mixer.!default
  {
    type oss
    device /dev/dsp
  }
  ```

Good luck

Comment: Is OSS4 better than PulseAudio?